# Search for files based on time created

Tags: powershell

I have a camera that takes one picture every hour of a structure being built.

This has generated 24 pictures a day for a year now and stored them in a folder.

There are too many night time pictures for an animation, so I would like to remove the pictures created between `xx/xx/xxxx 08:00 AM - xx/xx/xxxx 05:00 PM`.

Using Powershell or CMD, I would like to search for the files by time created, where the date is a wildcard (any date).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do the files have the times in their file names or do you want to use created date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like :

```
$source= get-ChildItem -Path  "C:\mappe\test" -filter "*.jpg"
$destination="c:\mappe"
$source |
    where { 
        (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -lt 17 -and (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -gt 8 
    }|
    Move-Item  -Destination $detination
```

Comment: this is powershell (ls is an alias for Get-ChildItem, like dir or gci )

Comment: I would like move the files created any date timestamp between 08:00 to 17:00 to another folder. How would you do this?

Comment: nothing seems to be happening, please excuse my lack of knowledge in this field..

Comment: ls 'C:\mappe\test\*.*' |where {(get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -lt 8 -and (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -gt 12} | Copy-Item -destination c:\mappe

Comment: `$source= ls 'C:\temp\*.jpg'   
$destination='c:\test'   
$source |where {   
 (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -lt 17 -and (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -gt 8 
}|  
Move-Item  -Destination $detination`  
Make sure $destination folder exist !

Comment: I created the directories, but get this error:Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At line:1 char:3
+ ls <<<<  'C:\temp\*.jpg' $destination='c:\test' $source |where { (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -lt 17 -and (get
-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -gt 8 }| Move-Item -Destination $detination
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Get-ChildItem C:\mappe\test | where { (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -lt 17 -and (get-date($_.creationTime)).Hour -gt 8 } | Move-Item -destination c:\mappe

Comment: Ok, got it working, but its just moving all the files, even the onces made created before 8:00 and after 17:00

Comment: I had to switch Creationtime with LastWriteTime. And now it works. THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

Give this is try. Change the filter wildcard to match your images extension. Files will move to the c:\NightPictures folder.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\pictures -Filter *.jpg | 
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Hour -gt 8 -and $_.CreationTime.Hour -lt 17} |
Move-Item -Destination c:\NightPictures
```

Comment: Shay is right, there's no need to use get-date to access Hour property